# DataTables 1.9 events capturing on hidden pages

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using DataTables 1.9 with multiple rows but only one visible column. Each cell in this column is a clickable div that shows a hidden content box, like a harmonica panel.

In this way I created a harmonica with on each DataTables page a number of panels (DataTable rows) and, depending on the number of panels the harmonica covers multiple (DataTable-) pages. On each harmonica header-panel I put a checkbox to mark specific rows for batch processing and other functions.

When selecting a checkbox
I stop the propagation of the 'click event’ by adding `event.stopPropagation` to the DIV that encompasses the checkbox in order to keep the harmonica panel closed (should only open when clicking on the harmonica panel outside the checkbox).

I thought everything functioned according to my wishes until I recently found out that this was only true for the first page that was rendered after the document loaded.  Checkboxes on other pages did not react at all when clicking on them. I found out that DOM elements on hidden DataTable-pages are not added to the DOM on initial page load. So in order to capture the click event on those checkboxes that were initially on a hidden DataTables-page I changed `$(".classname").on(“click", function(){…});`  to  `$(document).on(“click", ".classname”, function(){…});` This got the checkboxes on hidden DataTable-pages 
to react again to the click event.

But now, despite the `stopPropagation();` method, the click propagates to the harmonica panel and the panel opens.

I tried several options: putting the event.stopPropagation() directly in the html element and on several other locations. I tried combinations of jQuery’s `.click()`, `.on()`, `bind()`, `delegate()` (all within `$(document).ready`). So for now I have either a checkbox that functions esthetically and the harmonica keeps closed but the click does not trigger the associated event handler, or it does trigger the event handler but the click propagates as an unguided missile trough the page. I have no simple working example, sorry, but I hope someone recognizes the problem and can point to a solution.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Way too much to read. Perhaps you could wrap it up into a brief overview of the specific problem

Answer (score 0):

Read this part https://datatables.net/manual/events

*Note the use of the dt namespace when using the jQuery on() method, while the on() method will automatically append the namespace for you.*

So when you want to bind an event listening only to the datatables you need to add the following **namespace**: `.dt`

So your events binding should look something like this:

```
$(document).on("click.dt", ".classname”, function(){…}); // NOTE THE ".td" namespace at the event name
```

Now this event listener is only triggered by a datatable event.

You can manually trigger this specific event by calling:

```
$('.classname').trigger( "click.dt" );
```

This trigger will be ignored by all the other "regular" `click` event listeners on your page.

Comment: Found it! Although not your solution, thanks for making me dig deeper in the docs, Alon. Trick is to define event handlers prior to initializing the datatable :"Events which are assigned to the table elements are retained by DataTables such that they will still work as you would expect, even after changing the sort order etc. (no need to reapply the event handlers). If you apply the event handlers before you initialise DataTables, you just do this in the normal way."

Comment: @Peter Glad I was able to kind of help with that :)